# Automatically Binding Another Parameter in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In MVC this sort of thing is pretty trivial.  Let's say I have an MVC action signature:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(InjectedObject a, ConstructedObject b)
```

And let's say that the request from the client contains the `ConstructedObject` and I want to build the `InjectedObject` in the framework pipeline automatically.  (In this example, `InjectedObject` is on lots of actions, maybe even all of them.)  I could just create an `InjectedObjectModelBinder : IModelBinder` and register an instance of that binder when the application starts.

That binder would simply construct an instance of `InjectedObject` however I need to.  (From request data, from some other source, a combination of sources, etc.)  This worked really well for cross-cutting concerns.

---

However, is there a way to do this in WebAPI?  There's a new `IModelBinder`, but it seems like its use assumes only a single model on the input.  And my Googling so far has also pointed to that assumption.  Is it even possible in WebAPI to inject something into the pipeline like this as a cross-cutting concern while still having the constructed model from the post body?

The specific use case here is that I'd like to build a custom authorization-related object, in this case from request headers.  I could build it in the action, but every action would need to.  I could add an extension method onto the controller, but that would hurt unit testing.  The preferred method would be to simply inject it into the pipeline so that I can inject a mock when unit testing the controller actions.

Does WebAPI support this?  Or perhaps is there another preferred approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use an `IModelBinder` in the way you suggest, just ensure that the model binder handles (only) your `InjectedObject`. For example, the following simple model binder reads the header "your_key":

```
public class InjectedObjectModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(InjectedObject))
        {
            return false;
        }

        IEnumerable<string> values;
        string keyValue = "";

        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("your_key", out values))
        {
            keyValue = values.First();
        }

        bindingContext.Model = new InjectedObject() { Id = 789, Name = keyValue };

        return true;
    }
}
```

You then need to wire up the binder to the `InjectedObject` class. There are several ways of doing this:
Firstly, you could do it on each action method:

```
public void Post([ModelBinder(typeof(InjectedObjectModelBinder))]InjectedObject a, ConstructedObject b)
```

but this feels wrong given that you want to use this in many places. Secondly you could do it by decorating the `InjectedObject` class with the `ModelBinder` attribute:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(InjectedObjectModelBinder))]
public class InjectedObject
{....
```

Finally, you could add it to the `HttpConfiguration` in the `Register` method of the `WebApiConfig` class:

```
var provider = new SimpleModelBinderProvider(typeof(InjectedObject), new InjectedObjectModelBinder());
config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0, provider);
```

Given some simple `ConstructedObject` and `InjectedObject` implementations with the binder from above:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(InjectedObjectModelBinder))]
public class InjectedObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ConstructedObject
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

and an action method like this:

```
public void Post(InjectedObject a, ConstructedObject b)
{
    //a will be populated in our model binder.
}
```

and finally a request from Fiddler that looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:64577/api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:64577
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 51
your_key: This came from the header

{"a":1,"b":2,"c":"This was 'normal' model binding"}
```

The binding behaves as you would expect / hope:

[image: Watch window with correctly bound values]

A good article on model binding in Web API can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: Very detailed, thanks!  For some reason registering in the WebApiConfig isn't working for me, and debugging seems to indicate that the line calling it from Global.asax isn't being reached at all.  But that's unrelated and I can tinker with it later.  The proof of concept works fine if I decorate my action parameter.  It's a lot of repetition but I can live with that for now.  (I can't decorate the model since it's in the business domain and can't have a dependency on the application host technology.)  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @David, I guess you could register it directly in `Application_Start` using `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Insert(...` if it gets you round the problem for the time being?